# include javascript to google sites

Tags: javascript, google-sites

I've been trying to include a simple javascript to Google Sites. However it doesn't work when pressing the button. I put the code inside an HTML Box. The code works perfectly when tested locally. Here is my code:

```
<script>
function expandCollapse() {
for (var i=0; i<expandCollapse.arguments.length; i++) {
var element = document.getElementById(expandCollapse.arguments[i]);
element.style.display = (element.style.display == "none") ? "inline" :
"none";
}
}
</script>

<div id="L13a" style="display: inline;">
   <a href="javascript: expandCollapse('L13a', 'L13b');">Lent</a>
</div>

<div id="L13b" style="display: none;">
  <a href="javascript: expandCollapse('L13a', 'L13b');">Lent</a>
 <ul>

  <li><strong>tba</strong><br/>
    tba
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Is there something I made a stupid mistake?

Comment: Do you have any errors in the JS console in your browser dev tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your function to this:

```
function expandCollapse() {
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var element = document.getElementById(arguments[i]);
        element.style.display = (element.style.display == "none") ? "inline" :
            "none";
    }
}
```

And you should call it `onclick` and not in `href`

```
<div id="L13a" style="display: inline;"> <a onclick="expandCollapse('L13a', 'L13b');">Lent</a>

</div>
<div id="L13b" style="display: none;"> <a onclick="expandCollapse('L13a', 'L13b');">HI Lent</a>
```

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/TvHdU/